Can't open ftrace_enabled on android: No such device
I'm trying to execute tracee-ebpf-static on my android device and I ran into a fatal error regarding reading the ftrace_enabled node. This also happens when I try to cat it but not when I try to echo it.
{"level":"fatal","ts":1715874890.5336044,"msg":"App","error":"could not read from ftrace_enabled file: read /proc/sys/kernel/ftrace_enabled: no such device"}
Could someone give me an hand? I'm also not seeing any errors in logcat, so no idea what this could be.
My kernel: https://github.com/nitanmarcel/android_kernel_oneplus_sdm845/commits/lineage-21/
My defconfig: https://pastebin.com/8SFCb9iB
Should display a value,either 0 for disabled or 1 for enabled. Instead it shows an error: No such device
